# C++ delete duplicates from cstring

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a c-string that looks something like `ABBBCACACACBA` and I'm supposed to create a function that deletes the duplicate characters so I end up with `ABC`. I created a nested `for` loop that replaces every letter that matches the letter in the outer loop with a `\0` and increments a counter that keeps track of the repeats. I'm getting `-1` as the amount of repeats that should be documented, and from checking it spits out `ABBC` instead of `ABC`. I'm stumped, any ideas?

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < SIZE; j++)
    {
        if (letter[i] == letter[j])
        {
            letter[j] = '\0';
            repeatCounter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please paste your code as plain text, and make a [mre]

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Please edit your post with the text results of your debugging session.  Indicate the statement that is failing, the expected results and the actual results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not enough to just replace duplicates with `'\0'`, you have to actually remove them from the string and shift the remaining characters down.  Try something more like this:

```
int size = SIZE, i = 0;
while (i < size)
{
    int j = i + 1;
    while (j < size)
    {
        if (letter[j] == letter[i])
        {
            for (int k = j + 1; k < size; k++)
            {
                letter[k-1] = letter[k];
            }
            letter[--size] = '\0';
            repeatCounter++;
            continue;
        }
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/q7X2pt)

Comment: You're incredible, thank you.

Comment: I had a solution that looked similar to this but as a for loop but it wouldn't record the correct amount of repeats and would leave a repeated C in the array. I don't conceptually understand why.

Comment: @bambeezy a pitfall to watch out for when using a `for` loop is don't increment the index on *every* iteration, only on the ones that don't remove characters. Otherwise you end up skipping characters

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example which does what you want. It uses `std::string` to store the output. You can copy-n-paste the code [here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler) to test and run. Look into using `std::string` as it has functions which will make your life easy.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input("ABBBCACACACBA");
    string output;
    
    for(size_t i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
    {
        if(output.find(input[i]) == string::npos)
        {
            output += input[i];
        }
    }
    
    cout << "Input:  " << input << endl;
    cout << "Output: " << output << endl;

    return 0;
}
```